# Using SQLite FT3 in ASP.NET (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a data source which uses SQLite FTS3 tables.

I am trying to access them in ASP.NET (MVC) using the open source project https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Is there something I need to add to get FTS3 support, I am getting this error:

```
 no such module: FTS3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NuGet to get System.Data.Sqlite